# instagram api scopes "public_content"

Tags: api, instagram

We developed an app in sandbox mode that can display the density of Instagram content in a location on a map. We want to request all content with a hash tag and a location. With this data we populate a map.

All workers in the sandbox.

In the review for public content was rejected with:

> General issues: Invalid Use Case: The use case described in your
>   submission notes, screencast and website is not a valid use case that
>   we allow on our Platform. Please see our Permissions Review and valid
>   use cases description (https://www.instagram.com/developer/review/)
>   for more information. Invalid Use Case: The use case described in your
>   submission notes, screencast and website is not a valid use case. If
>   you are trying to display hashtag content for a one-off project (e.g.
>   a website for a brand, event or hashtag contest), note that we do not
>   support one-off and single use projects. We recommend that you use a
>   third-party platform that powers this use case. If you are building a
>   platform for this use case, we will only approve one client ID for all
>   your integrations. For more information, please see:
>   https://www.instagram.com/developer/review/

Yes our program is similar to a "hashtag contest" and this kind off applications get not approved.

My question:

Is there a way around this problem. How can you see list urls to pictures with hash tag and location on my page. Is there a recommendable third-party platform for this use case or any other option. I looked everywhere and it is just mentioned, that it is not possible. Dose anyone has an idea?

Answer (score -1):

Searching the content by hashtag is not Supported. if You are able to another way, better to change. Otherwise you use following platform.

[Recommendable third-party platform]
https://smashballoon.com/instagram-feed/demo/